# Django - Discard inline form value

Tags: django, django-forms

I've created a simple form Django Admin Form with a select field and a inline sub form. I would like that the fields of inline form were loaded only if the select field takes a value "example: 1".

It's possible? I've already overwrite the functions save_model and save_formset but without effect

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if form.fields['my_field']!="1":
        # discard inline

super(TaskAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Can someone help me?